# Como limpar/resetar bootstrap fileinput após de selecionar nova imagem?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando limpar/resetar após de selecionar nova imagem.

Após de selecionar imagem, limpar `Initial Preview`

Segue o código:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="input-pd" name="input-pd[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
```

**JS:**

```
$("#input-pd").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "/file-upload-batch/1",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 2,
    maxFileCount: 2,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    initialPreview: [
        // IMAGE DATA
        "http://kartik-v.github.io/bootstrap-fileinput-samples/samples/Desert.jpg",
        // IMAGE DATA
        "http://kartik-v.github.io/bootstrap-fileinput-samples/samples/Lighthouse.jpg"
    ],
    initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
    initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
    purifyHtml: true, // this by default purifies HTML data for preview
    uploadExtraData: {
        img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, places",
    }
}).on('filesorted', function(e, params) {
    console.log('File sorted params', params);
}).on('fileuploaded', function(e, params) {
    console.log('File uploaded params', params);
});

    $('#input-pd').on('change', function(event) {
        $('#input-pd').fileinput('clear');
        $('#input-pd').fileinput('reset');
        //$('#input-edit').fileinput('refresh');
    });
```

Aqui está em jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30077/

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Às vezes estamos tão concentrados a "*focar a imagem de perto quando deviamos estar a focar de longe*".

Penso que foi apenas uma falta de atenção no código. Se reparares bem tens ali uma opção desse plugin logo no início do código que diz:

```
overwriteInitial: false,
```

Basta apenas trocá-la para:

```
overwriteInitial: true,
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/DTcHh/30078/

```
$("#input-pd").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "/file-upload-batch/1",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 2,
    maxFileCount: 2,
    overwriteInitial: true,  /** <-- ###### Aqui está a opção a que me referi acima */
    initialPreview: [
        // IMAGE DATA
        "http://kartik-v.github.io/bootstrap-fileinput-samples/samples/Desert.jpg",
        // IMAGE DATA
        "http://kartik-v.github.io/bootstrap-fileinput-samples/samples/Lighthouse.jpg"
    ],
    initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
    initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
    purifyHtml: true, // this by default purifies HTML data for preview
    uploadExtraData: {
        img_key: "1000",
        img_keywords: "happy, places",
    }
}).on('filesorted', function(e, params) {
    console.log('File sorted params', params);
}).on('fileuploaded', function(e, params) {
    console.log('File uploaded params', params);
});

$('#input-pd').on('change', function(event) {
    $('#input-pd').fileinput('clear');
    $('#input-pd').fileinput('reset');
    //$('#input-edit').fileinput('refresh');
});
```